# How do you beat the dragon in Heroes of the Lance?

Tags: commodore-64

[Heroes of the Lance](http://www.lemon64.com/?mainurl=http://www.lemon64.com/games/details.php?ID=1192) was a game based on [DragonLance: Dragons of Autumn Twilight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Autumn_Twilight), utilizing the main characters from the book and letting you play their journey into Xak Tsaroth and confronting the black dragon.

In the book Goldmoon confronts the dragon with the Blue Crystal Staff. Assuming you were lucky enough to have her still alive in your party and the staff still had energy, as soon as you approached the dragon your entire party would immediately be killed.

A quick search didn't reveal any walkthroughs for the game that might tell me how to beat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never had played that game all the way through on the C64 but in the Nintendo version of it, you can defeat the dragon at the end by throwing the blue crystal staff at it.

The staff could be used by Goldmoon, Riverwind, Sturm or Caramon and the guys could only get it after Goldmoon croaked. In the NES version I killed the dragon using Caramon equipped the Blue Crystal Staff. (I only used Caramon because most of my other guys were dead by that point...)

[UPDATE:] I found a walkthrough for the NES version (If I recall correctly they were basically the same game):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/nes/587335-advanced-dungeons-and-dragons-heroes-of-the-lance/faqs/13758

Comment: Such as thing would have never occurred to me, occasionally I would try Raistin's "final strike" spell against the dragon, but never succeeded.